# Need a Excel Forumula to match a keywords column against another column

Tags: excel, formula, keyword

I need a Excel Formula to match a keywords column against another column and output the matching keywords in a column next to the first column.

This is what I am using now but it is not matching words but anything containing the keywords with in a word. I need it to match the entire word but not case sensitive..

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(ACONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Keywords,A9)),SUBSTITUTE(Keywords," ","^^"),"")," "))," ",", "),"^^"," ")
```

**Column 1:**

```
Decision/Step Name
```

New or existing facility applies for a new RCRA Permit to treat, store, or dispose of hazardous waste

Review permit application/modification for legal sufficiency

Incorporate legal comments in coordination with AFLOA/JACE

Obtain necessary approval signatures

Submit permit application/modification to State & US EPA

Review submitted permit application/modifications and provide comments

Revise permit application/modification to address comments and  resubmit to State & US EPA

Review and approve revised permit application/modification and develop an Internal Draft Permit (IDP)

Review IDP and submit any comments to State & US EPA for consideration

**Column 2:**

```
Keywords Return From Formula
```

RCRA Permit , permit, RCRA , RCRA Permit, PP

legal , permit, permit application/modification , PP

legal

PP

permit, permit application/modification , PP

permit, PP

DD, permit, permit application/modification , PP

draft permit, IDP, permit, permit application/modification , PP

IDP, State & US EPA

**Column 3:**

```
Keywords
```

RCRA

RCRA Permit

permit

State & US EPA

PP

IDP

permit application/modification

DD

draft permit

Answer (score 0):

Excel formulas cannot *insert* rows. They can only produce output for the current cell. You will need to look into VBA and the [`Range.Insert` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840310.aspx).

Comment: ok then i would just like the formula to find whole words only and not containing as mentioned in my post